Passport Carry in Taiwan
Are Americans (presumably foreign nationals) required to carry passport to prove standing to be in Taiwan?  I usually don't carry it outside the hotel room when I am outside the US.

not a big deal, but I think this is a many-times dupe

The question is specifically about requirement.
Generally, foreigners are required to carry identification and proof of status on them at all times. That's true in [almost] any country, including the US (that has such a requirement for foreigners, but not for own citizens).
Specifically, in Taiwan the law is (Immigration Act, Article 28):

An alien, who is aged of fourteen (14) or over, and has entered the State for a visit, residence or permanent residence, shall always carry his/her passport, Alien Resident Certificate, or Alien Permanent Resident Certificate


Apparently in the UK there's no legal requirement to carry identification for foreigners (at least that's what is claimed in the comments). That is the only such country I'm now aware of. Still, better assume there's such a requirement when traveling unless explicitly confirmed there isn't.
Also, while there's a requirement to carry the passport with you everywhere, as a practical matter you may be better off not to. But the question was about a requirement, not practical behavior.

"that's true in any country" this is false. In England & Wales for instance, whilst there are circumstances where one may have to prove ID and status in order to access certain services, the police can require you to provide ID and proof of status at the station at some later point, and border force can of course require such information at the border, it is not (legally) required for foreigners to carry ID and proof of status on them at all times (although it may make certain interactions with the police or state services smoother)

@Tristan Note that the police can be inaccurate when they say you are required to provide such proof the next day - they might mean within 24 hours, not a calendar day. Of course, there is no way of knowing that. The person you see at the station will roll their eyes and accept it, hopefully.

One thing to consider is what the legal meaning of "carry" is interpreted to be. Likely, it does not necessarily mean "having it physically on your person at all times, even while bathing" but having it somewhere readily accessible in a place where you have a reasonable expectation of security of your belongings.

@Tristan wasn't aware of such an exception, I've been to the UK many times and have always carried my passport with me.

In addition to the UK, there are other EU countries that do not require foreigners covered by the EU regulations on free movement (≈ people from Schengen countries) to carry identification. I would think such exceptions ought to apply in all Schengen countries, but I’m not sure on that.

These are not foreigner per se and have special rules. Let's not make this into another nit-picking debate, please. I know it's hard to sleep when you know someone is wrong on the internet, but I'd appreciate those who have anything else to say on the matter to either write their own answer or just move on.

Nitpicking aside, the general questions are "is there a requirement" and, if so, "does it make sense to comply with it" -- for example, in most of the US, it makes more sense to ignore it than to risk losing your passport.  What are the possible consequences of not carrying the documents specified in the law, and what is the probability of actually facing these consequences?

Also requirements aside I was recommended (by several different hotels' staff) to travel not with my passport but with a photocopy of my passport and the stamp page, supposedly due to higher levels of crime involving theft of passports in Thailand. I never got it checked by the police, but the claim was that they'd accept it.

Again, the question is about requirement. Not about does it make sense.

In most EEA countries (if not all), it's not a requirement to carry one's ID at all times, whether you're a citizen or a foreigner. There's no penalty for not carrying it, BUT under  certain circumstances, the police may detain you until they determine who you are. Carrying a form of ID is very important e.g. in Russia, most other ex-Soviet countries (notably except the Baltic countries), and Israel.

@Johnnyjanko don't forget the US. If you look the wrong way. But more to the point, even if what you're saying is true - you do realize it's still a small exception to a large rule. The world is much more than the EEA.

@littleadv is it mandatory to carry one's ID in the US? That sounds highly unlikely. In Russia or Israel it is mandatory.

@Johnnyjanko for foreigners? Yes, it is. And the CBP has the authority to check within 100 miles of a border, which includes international airports.

@littleadv I doubt CBP has authority to stop people 100 miles from any international airport.

@GerardAshton Depends who you ask and what you want to believe, of course. I've found no references to the whole law other than very critical ones (ACLU and such), but even they routinely mention patrols and checkpoints deep within the country.

Alternative opinion:
Yes, you are required to carry a passport, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to actually do it.
I never carry my passport unless I know I will need it (for travel, check-in, money exchange, etc). In Taiwan (as in China) my passport stays in the hotel safe.
The reasoning here is simple: Losing or having a passport stolen is a huge problem, whereas not being able to produce one when someone asks for it is a minor issue at best. In fact, I don't know what happens, since during my travels to 44+ countries in 40+ years, this has never happened to me.
So it comes down to a personal risk assessment. In my home country the original driver's license had a very awkward formfactor (small book). It was easy to lose and after having to pay for an expensive replacement, I decide not to carry it anymore. I got pulled over a few times without but most cops just told me off. Only once I had to pay a $5 fine which was a small fraction of the replacement cost.
Caveat: I'm a white male of average appearance and hence least likely to be profiled by most authorities (although that makes me
attractive for pickpockets and cops looking for bribes).

Yes, I think the caveat is important. Some people never get their ID checked, some people get it checked 3 times a day even in their own country, mostly based on their skin tone.

+1. Apart from the bit about the driving permit (which I’ve never had), this answer matches my experience to a T. I have been asked to show my passport on exactly zero of the fairly limited number of occasions where I’ve interacted with the police outside my own country (apart from contexts where I knew beforehand that I’d need it, of course, like when applying for a visa extension), but like you, I’m a white male of average appearance, and I’ve also been able to communicate in the local language nearly everywhere I’ve travelled.

I was asked for my passport at a police checkpoint in Bosnia. The two Canadians who I was traveling with only had photocopies and were detained. I always carry mine (since I tend to stay in hostels where I don't trust the security of the secure storage) and was allowed to continue. I didn't see them again in the 24 hours between that incident and when I left the hostel, so I don't know what the result of all that was. We were all white(ish) females. So for every "this has never happened to me" story there's going to be a counterpoint.

Just for reference, I (white male) once got asked for my passport or residence card in Japan exiting a store. I told the officer that my passport was in the hotel where I was staying for safety reasons and he escorted me back to prove it was really there (mind you the hotel was not even 5 minutes away by foot so that might have had a role in the escorting ordeal and YMMV). I got a bunch of weird looks walking with an officer by my side but aside from that there wasn't any problem

Re. China, not sure when you last spent time there, but nowadays they seem to require passports for every train ride and almost any tourist attraction.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: totally fair. I can only offer a data point of one. I certainly would carry it if there is reasonable expectations of a check point. I don't carry it, but I'm also not far from it either (if that makes sense).

@Jan: I haven't been since Covid but dozens of time before, mostly for work. I've never been asked on a subway or local train and on a long distance train I carry it anyway (since I'm on the move).

Last I've been to China was right before Covid, but my experience is similar - I've been asked to show my passport almost everywhere I went.

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas where in Bosnia and when?  I've spent a lot of time there since 2004, mostly in Sarajevo, and was stopped only once at a road checkpoint (which are frequent, but I've only ever been stopped once).  Since I was driving to another country, I had my passport.  I don't carry it normally, and as far as I can tell being asked for ID as a pedestrian is rare.

@phoog Sarajevo, near the airport, in a taxi. This would've been around 2019.

Always good to hear the counter-argument / devil's advocate
